# xlsx to json with empty cells

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, xlsx

I'm converting a file from xlsx format to json, I can do it correctly, but I could not get it to show the cells that are empty, just ignore them.
I am using the XLSX library.
This is the code with which I do the parsing.

```
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(filename);
        const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
        let jsonPagesArray = [];
        sheet_name_list.forEach(function(sheet) {
                const jsonPage = {
                    name: sheet,
                    content: XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet])
                };
                jsonPagesArray.push(jsonPage);
            });
        res.json(
            {
                data:jsonPagesArray
            }
        );
        });
```

actually if a give this:

```
xxx1 | xxx2 | xxx3
------------------
yyyy | yyyy | 
zzzz | zzzz | zzzz
```

it return me:

```
    [
        {
            xxx1:yyyy,
            xxx2:yyyy
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            xxx1:zzzz,
            xxx2:zzzz,
            xxx3:zzzz
        }
    ]
```

i want it return me something like this:

```
    [
        {
            xxx1:yyyy,
            xxx2:yyyy,
            xxx3:""
        }
    ],
    [
        {
            xxx1:zzzz,
            xxx2:zzzz,
            xxx3:zzzz
        }
    ]
```

Answer (score 56, accepted):

can you replace `content: XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet])` with `content: XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet], {defval:""})` in your code and try again?

Comment: You are a gem dude.Saved the day.

Comment: You are legend!

Answer (score 4):

You can use

```
XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(worksheet , {defval:""})
```

Comment: this question has already an accepted answer and your answer doesn't add new information

Answer (score 3):

This should work. [Working example](https://repl.it/repls/DeliriousAuthenticOperatingenvironment)

```
let XLSX = require('xlsx');
const workbook = XLSX.readFile(filename);
const sheet_name_list = workbook.SheetNames;
let jsonPagesArray = [];
sheet_name_list.forEach(function(sheet) {
        const jsonPage = {
            name: sheet,
            content: JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(XLSX.utils.sheet_to_json(workbook.Sheets[sheet],{defval:""})))
        };
        jsonPagesArray.push(jsonPage);
    });

console.log(jsonPagesArray[0].content);
```